# Watching a table for change in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database

Is there a better way to watch for new entries in a table besides selecting from it every n ticks of time or something like that?

I have a table that an external program updates very often, and clients can watch for this new data as it arrive, how can I make that without having to set a fixed period of repeatable select statements?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [MySQL listen notify equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031723/mysql-listen-notify-equivalent)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In MySQL there's no best way than to poll (you create a specific table to simplify the polling though), in other databases you can have triggers that have impact outside the database. In MySQL [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) can only do stuff inside the database itself (for instance, populating the helper table).

Answer (score 10):

Another similar approach would be to add

```
add column Last_Modified TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

to each table and preface your select queries to compare the last request date/time with the max(Last_Modified).

Databases are typically *pull* sources and not *push* so you'll still need to programmatically probe for changes no matter what.

Answer (score 8):

Here's what I do:
I've got some triggers set up for the table (insert, delete, update) and those triggers increment a counter in another table.  My DB access code keeps a local counter and compares it to the returned value, ultimately sending a bool back to the caller, answering the question IsDataCurrent().

Our programs that use this DB access code either poll or check it on-request and then make the appropriate calls to keep themselves up to date.

I'm sure there are other ways to solve this.  It worked for me pretty well, though.

Comment: So it still requires polling, only slightly better to poll: select * from lastupdatetable; versus select count(*) from datatable;

Comment: I disagree.  The query select count(*) might produce erroneous results.  If I perform an add/ a delete/ and an add the count will be the same, right?  So did the data change?  You wouldn't know in that case.  The last update table won't produce this situation.

Comment: But it still requires a select every n ticks, but that would be more low cost than selecting the actual data table, that's a way I'm considering too.

Answer (score 6):

It is *possible* to trigger behaviour outside the database, if you have control of the host.

A)
[This question's answer suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686148/monitor-mysql-table-for-changes-within-a-c-sharp-program?lq=1) writing to a file using 'select into outfile' with some system process watch that file for changes (e.g. inotify-based approach such as [node-inotify](https://github.com/c4milo/node-inotify) or even a [Grunt-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) might suffice)

B) For the brave: 
[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418598/is-there-a-way-to-watch-a-mysql-database-for-changes-using-perl) points out that if you can install C/C++ add-ons to your database server, you could use a User Defined Function (UDF) to call sys_exec() and thus trigger external processes, or presumably write the actual process directly in the UDF.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-11

(I'm researching this at the moment, for an AWS RDS hosted application so unfortunately neither of these options are right for me.)

Answer (score 1):

This is just a small improvement to your method.  Write a trigger on the table(s) you are watching to update a Last_Changed table.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are doing this in go. You can enable binlog and read binlog for new insert/update/delete on any table. There is a go package [here](https://github.com/siddontang/go-mysql) that does the trick. And [here](https://github.com/JackShadow/go-binlog-example) is a sample implementation.