# Sending message from mysql

Tags: mysql, c, sockets, stomp, udf

I there any way so send message from mysql database to my app? It can be on local machine and send via UNIX socket.
I want to trigger this function and send message to my app that will track changes in database.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031723/mysql-listen-notify-equivalent

Comment: You can write a user defined function in C and perhaps send the message from there.

Comment: Also, you have to be sure you can't send the message manually after updating the database, it shouldn't be too hard to abstract such a function and make it work for all queries.