# Notification dispatch when MySQL database table change

Tags: mysql, postgresql, notifications

Currently I have a real time notification system built on Postgres , Nodejs, Socket.IO, which is working on perfectly on my production servers.

I used Postgres LISTEN / NOTIFY Feature.

example

http://bjorngylling.com/2011-04-13/postgres-listen-notify-with-node-js.html

Currently I have a requirement to migrate MySQL. Is there any similar facility like NOTIFY available on MySQL.

Or Is there any proper solution for replicate same function using MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL listen notify equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031723/mysql-listen-notify-equivalent)