# how does client get to know when there is a change (table update)in the server database?

Tags: python, mysql, sockets, networking, websocket

---

Is there any way to access the server database when there is a change in the server database without sending a continuous request to the server from the client?
I can access the data from server database by sending continuous request to server but i do not want to send the request everytime.how will i be able to know there is a change in the server database and send the request only when there is a change in the database?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Not without some kind of a service that can tell your client that the database was moved somewhere else.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by change - move db to another server, change db name, change data in existing db, something else..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Watching a table for change in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167254/watching-a-table-for-change-in-mysql)

Comment: @P.Salmon whenever there is a change in the table

Answer (score -1):

Apache Kafka can be used for this particular use case..
https://kafka.apache.org/uses